# Recursive realtion solution in terms of variable(p)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
u[0, 0] =1
u[m, n] =(1/(p + m + m^2)) (m*u[(m - 1), n] + n*u[(m + 1), (n - 2)] + m*(m - 1)*u[(m - 2), (n + 2)])
```

I want `u[m,n]` in terms of `p`; don't want answer like `u[0,2]=2u[1,0]/p` only in terms of `p`; like I want value of `u[m,n]` for different value of `m` and `n`.

Comment: Which is it it? Matlab or Mathematica?

Comment: If the second line of code is intended to be a function definition it is seriously flawed.  Read the documentation of basic function definition, figure out patterns for argument matching and study `SetDelayed`

Comment: u[0,0]=1 is intial condition; I want algorithm for u[m,n], and function is right there is no problem with that, could you help me for algorithm?

Comment: let m = 1, n = 1. The function then goes for u[(m-2), (n+2)] which is u[-1, 3]. That then goes and fetches u[-3, 5] and so on infinitely. Function IS flawed. 
and High Performance Mark means your syntax for a function declaration is flawed. Use `u[m_, n_] := `

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Jonie Shih your recursion doesn't terminate.  Perhaps you want to terminate for either argument less than one:

```
u[x_, y_] /; x < 1 || y < 1 = 1;

u[m_, n_] :=
 (1/(p + m + m^2)) (m*u[(m - 1), n] + n*u[(m + 1), (n - 2)] + 
    m*(m - 1)*u[(m - 2), (n + 2)])

p = 4;
u[3, 5]
```

> ```
> 593037/1392640
> ```